# How to create an increasing counter of ranges?

Tags: python

In a script I'm running, there is a memory leak issue (due to the proprietary software being used) that prevents a script for running for more than about 325k iterations. To get around this, I created a list of values for it to iterate through in a `for` loop like so:

```
squery = 
['OBJECTID >=0 AND OBJECTID <=300000',
'OBJECTID >=300001 AND OBJECTID <=600000',
'OBJECTID >=600001 AND OBJECTID <=900000',
....
'OBJECTID >=8700001 AND OBJECTID <=8766184']

for query in squery:
    do work
```

Is there a method to create these ranges in 300k intervals so that the list can be built at runtime with a intervals until the value reaches X? As in, 3 intervals for 900k records, and 5 intervals for 1.5 million records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
squery =
['OBJECTID>=%s AND OBJECTID<=%s' % (i*300k+(i!=0),(i+1)*300k) for i in range(0,3)]
```

(300k = 300 000 and number of intervals is in `range(0,*3*)`)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had no idea you could create lists this way!

Comment: it's called `list comprehensions`: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: I'm familiar with those, just not this method for using them. There's always more to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, a generator would also solve this problem nicely:

```
def generator_function(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        yield ('OBJECTID>=%s AND OBJECTID<=%s' % (i*300000+(i!=0),(i+1)*300000))

# now use it:
for each_string in generator_function(3):
    print each_string
```

This method generates each string on the fly, so in some situations might be preferable (for example if you want to generate a huge number of strings rather than just 5 - in which case itertools is a good companion to generators).

Comment: Thanks for the alternate method.